# How to reduce memory consumption of AJDT?

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj, ajdt

I have situations when I need to load 20-30 projects in Eclipse Workspace.
Most of the projects require AspectJ weaving. Currently we are using LTW, but want to move to CTW. The problem is that with 12 AJDT projects in workspace I get around 1Gb "eaten" by some AJDT stuff after full rebuild. I already use AJDT compiler options

> -Xset:minimalModel=true,typeDemotion=true

It helps, but not much. Is there any way to switch off cross references view and wipe out all information needed for this view. I really do not need it. I was happy w/o it with LTW.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to "Help" -> "Installation Details" and on the "Installed software" tab locate "Cross References tool (XRef)". Then you could try uninstalling it and see what happens. Maybe the XRef tool is the culprit, maybe just the weaving step during compilation is, depending on how many classes you have and how broadly you apply AspectJ to your code base.

[image: Eclipse installation details dialogue]

Comment: I have made further experiments and It looks like AJDT "eats" memory even in projects w/o aspects.  So probably deleting XRef Tool will not help.

Comment: Would you mind trying anyway instead of just making assumptions? I spent time creating the description and screenshot for you. Thanks. And BTW, I see no such problems with AJDT eating memory (other than the memory needed minimally for the plugin as such) in non-aspect projects.

Comment: I have tried:
1. Checkout 12 projects in Eclipse, 2 Convert all AJDT, 3 Full rebuild (Project / Clean. ..all) - got Heap Size: 950 Mb 4. Uninstalled XRef 5 Restarted Eclipse w/o rebuild - got 108Mb 6. After full rebuild - 920Mb 7. After removing AspectJ capability and full rebuild - 197Mb

Comment: Maybe you want to open an AJDT ticket.

Comment: I have decided to create my own Maven plugin to apply aspects. Because neither AJDT nor aspectj-maven-plugin do not fit my needs.

Comment: I would be interested in trying your plugin when it is done, just because I am curious - mostly due to the fact that I like AspectJ Maven Plugin and am wondering what might be better or more adequate in yours.

Comment: I can explain: 1. It does not support (same as ajc) weaving of individual .class files. I need it for incremental builds in Eclipse. 2. It cannot properly process test dependencies in Eclipse (when dependency is in workspace). Though in this case it is probably M2E fault or some missconfiguration. I do not even know if it is possible to make M2E to properly resolve tests class path.

Comment: Maybe you want to consider contributing to AJDT. Andrew Eisenberg and Andy Clement are nice guys, I am sure they warmly welcome you if you can help to improve something. Good luck! :-)